# SharePoint 2016 Topology Planning

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, topology

Im trying to figure out how to properly size my SP 2016 farm(migration from SP2010), select proper roles for the servers etc.

I have two possible approaches in mind:

1. 8 Servers(2x each MinRole) plus SQL Servers
2. 4 Servers(2x each Shared Role(WFE + Distributed Cache/APP + Search)) - Similar to current 2010 scenario

I understand the benefits of it scenario but I having a little trouble figuring out which fits best the following scenario:

- 800~ Users
- 3 TB Data + growth of 30GB/month
- 4 WebApp, 80 site collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 800 users (more important, how many concurrent?), I would suggest the smaller of the two topologies for now using the shared MinRoles.

With the size of the index, I would suggest, in the future, looking at adding 2 or more additional Search servers (either App+Search, or stand alone Search).

Comment: So the most import thing to consider is the number of (concurrent)users when assessing the topology? Well, it shouldn't be more than 200~ concurrent, probably less. Another question: By using the Share Roles, do I lose the auto-configuration of the services as in the min roles?

Comment: Concurrent is the most important since that is what will be putting load on many of the services. The content size is also important, especially with regards to Search (crawling being the most CPU heavy activity). As for shared MinRoles, no they will still autoconfigure.